# Jquery replace class only works one way

Tags: jquery, class, addclass, removeclass

For a school project i'm making a social media page and i've come to the point I have to make a follow/unfollow button. I've made 2 classes. One class (class1) that looks like a normal button and one (class2) that looks like that button is pressed.

Normally class1 is chosen but when you click the button I want to show class2 and it should show the "unFollow" text.

I want it to work both ways. So when I click on the button that now has the class2 turns to class1 but that's the thing I can't fix.

Here's my code down below :

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".FollowB").click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("FollowButton")
        $(this).addClass("unFollowButton")
        $(this).text("Unfollow")
    }); 
});

if $(this).hasClass("unFollowButton"){
    $(this).removeClass("unFollowButton")
        $(this).addClass("FollowButton")
        $(this).text("Follow")
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code and even more important **why it's not working?**

Comment: You need to put the if statement inside the click callback with the code that is already in there in an else statement

Comment: 1. You use class .FollowB and FollowButton? 2. $(this) in the first context uses class FollowB and $(this) in second context uses window since it is no bind to a click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem appears to be the second `if` is outside of the `$(document).ready()` handler, and its `$(this)` is the global Window object, not the button itself.

The easiest way to verify that is to simply `console.log($(this))` prior to the `if`.

The simplest way to implement your functionality, though, is:

```
// I'm assuming the relevant buttons are of class="FollowB"
// *and* they start with a class of either 'follow' or 'unfollow':
$(".FollowB").on('click', function () {
    // $(this) is the clicked .FollowB button-element:
    $(this)
        // toggleClass replaces 'follow' with 'unfollow'
        // and vice-versa; removing the present-class and
        // adding the non-present class:
        .toggleClass('follow unfollow')
        // using the anonymous function of text() to
        // update the text:
        .text(function(){
            // if the clicked element has the class 'follow'
            // we set the text to 'unfollow, if it does not
            // then we set the text to 'follow':
            return $(this).hasClass('follow') ? 'unfollow' : 'follow';
        });
    });
```

```js
$(".FollowB").on('click', function() {
  $(this)
    .toggleClass('follow unfollow').text(function() {
      return $(this).hasClass('follow') ? 'unfollow' : 'follow';
    });
});
```

```css
button {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.unfollow {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
.follow {
  border: 2px solid #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="FollowB unfollow">Follow</button>
```

References:

- [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/);
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: The way you explain it, makes sense to me.. But still it doesn't seem te work?

$(".FollowB").on('click', function () {
 $(this).toggleClass('FollowButton unFollowButton')
 .text(function(){
  return $(this).hasClass('FollowButton') 'unfollow' : 'follow';
 });
});

Comment: Doesn't it? It works in the posted demo; if it doesn't work for you then tell me in what way it "doesn't work," your statement is not a bug-report (or at least it's not an effective one). If you can make a ***minimal*** **[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)** [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo to reproduce your problem that would be much appreciated, cut it down to the minimum code necessary to reproduce your problem and provide a link to that demo.

Comment: And now that I've included jQuery (see that drop-down menu at the top left, below "Frameworks & Extensions"?), corrected the typo (the missing `?` in the `return $(this).hasClass('follow') ? 'unfollow' : 'follow';` *and* added the `FollowButton` class in the HTML (did you read the comments in the code?), it seems to work. Certainly on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/42c6urph/3/). If you don't want us to make assumptions about your HTML then *show us your HTML in the question*. Otherwise we can *only* guess, and guessing is almost always bad.

Comment: Can't stand it!! It doesn't seem to work here.. It doesn't do anything when i click the button.. Even when I copied the exact same on Js Fiddle.. 

http://jsfiddle.net/frd6qkjq/

Above is my code.. Haha I know it isn't that good but i'm trying to build a social media website for a school project and I just started coding! You have to watch the code in full screen because it's not responsive

Comment: It's like you're not reading...I realise that your native language isn't English, so first, my apologies. Now: to use jQuery on JS Fiddle ***you*** have to specify that jQuery should be used, there is a <select> element on the top-left, below the 'Extensions & Frameworks' header. From that select the version of jQuery to use. Next, the HTML was written on the assumption that the `follow` or `unfollow` class would be present on the `<button>`. If neither is there then the jQuery adds *both* classes. Now: *either* post your actual (relevant) HTML in your question...

Comment: ...or you need to read the answer properly, and pay attention to what you're doing.

Comment: Haven't used document.ready.. that was my problem lol... Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(".foo").click(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass('follow')) {
     $(this).removeClass("follow")
     $(this).addClass("unfollow")
     $(this).text("Unfollow")
   } else {
     $(this).removeClass("unfollow")
     $(this).addClass("follow")
     $(this).text("follow")
   }
 });
```

```css
.follow {
  color: red;
}
.unfollow {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='foo follow'>Follow</div>
```